# How to update DataGridView from BindingList C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Forms application. It has a DataGridView called dgvCalendar. The dgv pulls data from a database, and I've confirmed (as far as I know how to) that there are no issues there.

The form also has has two buttons: btnAll, which displays all of the appointments in the calendar and works as expected; btnMonth which should show only the appointments in the current month.

I've confirmed that there is at least 1 appointment in my current month, but when I click that button, the dgv just goes blank.

If I click the btnAll, it populates again as expected.

```
public partial class Main: Form
{
    // I know that this populates from the database correctly
    static BindingList<Appointment> allAppts = DbManager.GetAppointmentsByUserId();

//...

private void btnAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This works just fine
    dgvCalendar.DataSource = null;
    dgvCalendar.DataSource = allAppts;
}

private void btnMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE IS...

    DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    System.Globalization.Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

    // MessageBox output is "My Month: 3" which is what I expect (it's March)
    MessageBox.Show("My Month: " + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()); 
    
    dgvCalendar.DataSource = null;
    dgvCalendar.DataSource = allAppts.Where( 
        a => DateTime.Parse(a.start).Month == DateTime.Now.Month
    ); 
}

//...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is when the code is filtering the `BindingList`. When the code applies the filter like…

```
dgvCalendar.DataSource = allAppts.Where(
         a => DateTime.Parse(a.start).Month == DateTime.Now.Month);
```

this is returning an `IEnumerable<Appointment>`, which the grid obviously does not handle.

Fortunately, converting the `IEnumerable` to a list by adding `.ToList()` to the end of the line of code should display the filtered data in the grid as expected. Something like…

```
dgvCalendar.DataSource = allAppts.Where(
         a => DateTime.Parse(a.start).Month == DateTime.Now.Month).ToList();
```

Also, it appears you are storing the dates as a `string` which is only going to create more work for you. I suggest you store the dates as `DateTime` objects.

Comment: Beautiful! That did it. I didn't realize the filter was returning an `IEnumerable`. Now I know. Thank you!